# Stabilizing the colormap range to compare two surface plot diagrams in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, surface, colormap

Whatever I tried I couldn't stabilize the colors of two diagrams. When the values decrease from 0 - 30 to 0-1 the colormap always adapts to new values. In the figures attached, I need to stabilize the first color scale 0-30, and second legend should by all dark blue as well as the surface.

Disregard the y-values.

[image: 0-30]
[image: 0-1]

Thank you so much for all your help and advices.

The partial code is below.

```
args = {time,freq,abs(cfs).^2}; 
surf(args{:},'edgecolor','none'); 
view(0,90); axis tight; 
shading interp; colormap(parula(128)); 
h = colorbar;
```

I tried this but didn't work.

```
set(h,'ylim',[0 100]); 
yal=linspace(1,100);
set(h,'ytick',yal);
```

Comment: Can you put an example of the code you are using? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this instead:

```
caxis([0 100]);
```

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html

Comment: Thank so you much Flynn. It's really what I was looking for.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help